# How to copy data from one column to another column using Office Scripts?

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I'm currently working on automating some tasks in Microsoft Excel using Office Scripts, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to copy data from one column to another.

[image]

I want to copy Date column(D) data to New_Date column(F).

Any help or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code copy Col `Date` to Col `NewDate`.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // modify table name as needed
    let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1"); 
    let srcRange = table1.getColumn("Date").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    let targetCell = table1.getColumn("New_Date").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRow(0);
    targetCell.copyFrom(srcRange, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
}
```